# Netplan: unknown key '<<' (YAML anchor and dictionary merge syntax)

Tags: networking, netplan

I am trying to add multiple static routes with shared `via` and `table` using YAML anchor syntax. This is an example `custom.yaml` file:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: false
      accept-ra: false
      addresses:
        - 192.0.2.2/24
      gateway: 192.0.2.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
      routing-policy:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          table: 2 # custom
          priority: 10
      routes:
        - &custom-route
          to: 198.18.0.0/24
          via: 192.0.2.1
          table: 2
        - <<: *custom-route
          to: 198.18.2.0/24
        - <<: *custom-route
          to: 198.18.4.0/24
```

*While it is not my actual config file, to the best of my knowledge, it should demonstrate and reproduce the problem I'm facing.*

When running `netplan apply`, this is the output I got:

```
/etc/netplan/custom.yaml:48:11: Error in network definition: unknown key '<<'
        - <<: *custom-route
          ^
```

Is there any way I could achieve this?

In case it matters, my server cluster contains a mixture of Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 systems. It would be best if a solution applies to both versions.

Comment: Your error is that Netplan doesn't recognize `<<` as a key.  Can you show where you are seeing that being used as a key in a Netplan configuration that works or where it is used in the official documentation?  I cannot find it in the references:  https://netplan.io/reference

Comment: @Terrance `<<` is not a "key". It's part of YAML syntax. See https://ktomk.github.io/writing/yaml-anchor-alias-and-merge-key.html for example.

Comment: I haven't used Netplan in a very long time as I find it finicky, but I believe that keys are specified as `name:` where it is seeing `<<:` as a key.  In your documentation there it shows it being used as `<< :` with a space between the `<<` and the `:`.  Netplan is very picky about spacing.

Comment: As you can see in my answer, merge keys are actually deprecated...

Answer (score 4):

It is properly confirmed that netplan does not support merge keys.

This means a less fancy config is needed:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: false
      accept-ra: false
      addresses:
        - 192.0.2.2/24
      gateway: 192.0.2.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
      routing-policy:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          table: 2 # custom
          priority: 10
      routes:
        - to: 198.18.0.0/24
          via: 192.0.2.1
          table: 2
        - to: 198.18.2.0/24
          via: 192.0.2.1
          table: 2
        - to: 198.18.4.0/24
          via: 192.0.2.1
          table: 2
```

From the [page you reference](https://ktomk.github.io/writing/yaml-anchor-alias-and-merge-key.html):

> #### Caveat: Support of Merge Keys
>
> Support in (YAML versions is different / is different per) specific
> YAML versions:
>
> - Anchors and Aliases are part of YAML since 1.0, part of YAML 1.1 and current YAML 1.2.
> - Merge Keys are only part of YAML 1.1 which is deprecated, not part of YAML 1.2 nor 1.0. That means that Merge Keys are born deprecated.
>   Technically this is not possible in a specification, which may explain
>   that Merge Key Language-Independent Type for YAML™ Version 1.1 is a
>   working draft with a single instance only. It appears to fall into the
>   general availability of the YAML 1.1 release.
> - According to Flyx in a posting on Stackoverflow and also from the YAML RFCs (Ingy döt Net, Tinita), Merge Keys are born deprecated with
>   YAML 1.1.
> - The SO post 2017 suggests to replace Merge key/s with "something better" in an upcoming YAML version (best guess YAML 1.3 unreleased
>   Nov 2020), the RFC index has the note "Remove Merge Key" (Brian
>   Ingerson / Ingy döt Net) verbatim to make the removal a new RFC.

This is the reason why merge keys does not work with Netplan.

Comment: Maybe anchors and merges can't be used with dashes? I'm not an expert in `yaml` syntax, unfortunately. 

Comment: Confirm: Netplan recognizes both `&tag` and `*tag`, just not the merge key. I suppose you're right.